# What tool works for real-time tweaking of CSS in IE6, similar to what Firebug does for Firefox? 

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser, firebug

All front-end developers know the pain of coding for Firefox, then viewing our then mangled pages in IE6. 
IE6 is still widely used (it is, however disappearing [slowly but surely](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp)... in a year and a half from the writing of this, it will be irrelevant as usage will be less than 1%)
We usually used IE conditional comments to create separate CSS files for IE to render correctly. It would be great if there was a tool like Firebug for IE6. Firebug "lite" exists but it seems to be very beta and the new IE8 has an excellent built in developer tool that in many ways is better than firebug) What's the best tool for IE6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know [Debugbar](http://www.debugbar.com/) is currently the most sophisticated debugging tool for IE. It's definitely better than IE developer, but it's still not quite as slick as firebug.

Answer (score 2):

I used to use [IE Developer Toolbar](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2007/01/09/ie-developer-toolbar-beta-3-now-available.aspx) as a sort of Firebug alternative. While I don't think it allows you to enter normal CSS, you can adjust the CSS as a list of name/value pairs (adding, editing, removing, etc).

Answer (score 1):

[Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) seems to be the best option.